# How does the Electrum wallet encryption work?

Tags: security, encryption, electrum

Nube bitcoin question...  I created an electrum wallet, and can find it under appdata on my windows machine.  When creating it I set up a pass phrase and password.  I sent a small transaction into one of the addresses.

I read in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Electrum/Documentation that this procedure should encrypt the wallet.dat file.  Looking at the wallet.dat in a text editor before restarting electum, it does not appear encrypted in it's entirety, and to me it is not obvious what in there is encrypted.  Perhaps only the private keys are encrypted?  Also when I start up electrum, there is no prompt for a password to decrypt anything.

Is it explained anywhere how I can see evidence that encryption is in place?  Perhaps I should take that small amount of bitcoin now in my wallet and figure out how to send it somewhere else, and it will all become clear?

Comment: Try sending some coins out of the electrum wallet. Does that require the password?

Comment: I did send bitcoin out, and before sending, it did prompt for my password.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like only the private keys are encrypted. Your addresses are stored unencrypted, so the software can show your balance without requiring a password.